# curl and command line

Tags: php, curl, vagrant

I have a vagrant `virtual box` host with `ubuntu` and I developed a `command line` app with `PHP`.

This app runs as a service and like this:

```
secret_user@homestead:~$ generate-code getNewCode
```

this command line return:

```
34Nc88MThWF6aVEcenzN2qJfTjg3KEkddD
```

now I want to access from another app inside `index.php` send a curl request to this command line app

```
<?php

$getNewCode = curl( with address or localhost, port , user and password)
```

Is this posiable?

Comment: `curl` is for sending requests to a webserver, you don't use it to run local commands. Use `shell_exec()`

Comment: So I can define a domain for vagrant and it is same as a web server!
How can I define user and port with shell_exec?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Vagrant, but it looks like you can use `vagrant ssh -c 'generate-code getNewCode'` from the host to execute a command on the guest.

Comment: [Curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) actually supports several network protocols: "libcurl currently supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap protocols". But it's pretty unclear if there's any network involved here. Are both `generate-code` and `index.php` inside the VM? Do you want to expose services to the host machine?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes for testing inside VM, But I will put them two separate host and domain

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you suppose I have a host with 192.168.10.10 ip and I have a a.com domain- on host with ip and ssh I have a command line app and on a.com I have index.php

Comment: The term "host" is too generic and doesn't mean the same in the context of virtual machines and web servers. How many different machines (either virtual or bare metal) are involved in the execution of `generate-code` and `index.php` and how do they communicate each other? Is there an HTTP server involved?

Comment: I have a VM.It has an IP: 192.168.10.10  I ssh to in and in /vagrant/code/a.php wrote an script that works with command line, I created a service for this, but this is not in root user,another user and password, so I have in root user in vagrant/code/index.php and I want to access that command line inside index.php

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Next I want to separate these two. index.php on https://a.com can access https://176.128.2.2 with ssh that generate-code runs on it.